# Difference between spawn_handle() and spawn_essential_handle()

Tags: service

Currently this is how I am making a `transaction_pool` for a Light service

```
let transaction_pool = Arc::new(sc_transaction_pool::LightPool::new_light(
        config.transaction_pool.clone(),
        config.prometheus_registry(),
        task_manager.spawn_handle(),
        client.clone(),
        on_demand.clone(),
    ));
```

and the compiler is unhappy about `task_manager.spawn_handle()` not implementing SpawnEssentialNamed. So I look at the docs and find a `spawn_essential_handle()` which fixes the error.

My question out of curiousity is why are there two versions of `spawn_handles`? I can read and make out that `spawn_essential_handle` is supposed to take the node down with it if the task it spawned failed. Any other differences we should know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is the difference.

The idea is that you can spawn these essential tasks and if the future resolves it means the node needs to stop. For example because the import pipeline stopped working. Otherwise there is no difference.